# Generate Unique id for each Employee of each Company using Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create unique id for each Employee of company. For example currently I am getting like this.

Company has many employees and employee belongs_to company

```
 company1= employee1
 company1 = employee2
 company1 = employee3
 company2 = employee4
 company2 = employee5
```

So, here employee id's are not getting changed while company_id is changed.

So, I want something like this:
For each company employee_id should start with 1.
like

```
  Company1 = employee1
  company1 = employee2
  company1 = employee3
  company2 = employee1
  company2 = employee2
```

Could anyone please help me how to do that in Rails5?

employee table

```
     id    name      position
     1     aaa       eg_position
     2     vvv        qqq
```

company table

```
    id    name     
    1     xxx
    1     yyy
```

so present its storing like 
       xxx - 1, yyy-2
I want like this xxx-1.yyy-1

Comment: you shouldnt worry or change ids . Rails takes care of it for you . If you try to manipulate model ids yourself you may experience bugs . I don't understand at all why you need to do this

Answer (score 0):

Use uniqueness validation based on scope of composite key. `employee_id` and `company_id`

`validates :employee_id, uniqueness: {scope: [:employee_id, :company_id]}`

Answer (score 0):

We have to be very clear.

I am assuming that you have an employees table where all employees of all different companies are stored.

If that is the case, then you cannot have two primary keys which are the same. You cannot do this.

But what you can do is have another field, perhaps employee number (which is different to id) which can be the same across different employees in different companies.

Personally i don't like the idea of a composite primary key.

What I would do is create another column in your table called: employee number. And use that to store what you call: "id"

I hope this helps.

**edit:**

Further explanations.

Every row in a table has a column called "id". this is a special name. this is the name of the "primary key". Don't change that name. Two rows in the same table cannot have the same "id" or primary key. You can't do it. It's fundamental to a database. you can't have the same primary key in two rows of the same table - for mysql, psql, Access etc.

but you want to identify two employees with the same "identification number". That's fine. You can do it. Just don't call the employee identification number: "id" because that won't work. You can call it "employee_no" and that would work fine.

show my your database schema and we can further clarify.

hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain it more?